# print XML/XSLT data via CGI

Tags: xml, xslt, cgi

I have a Perl-CGI script that gets data from a server in XML format. The data is collected in a variable.
I created a XSLT sheet and modified the variable to add XSLT tag in it.
However, it fails to load the XSLT document.

Here's the code snippet:

```
my $retData = &postData($qStr); <--- Gets data from server
my @val = split("\n",$retData);
$curr_index = 0;
my @temp_arr;
for my $temp (@val) {
   if ($curr_index == 0) {
      push(@temp_arr,$temp);
        push(@temp_arr,"\<\?xml-stylesheet type\=\"text\/xsl\" href\=\"myquery.xsl\"\?\>");
       } else {
         push @temp_arr,$temp;
       }
      $curr_index++;
    }
    @val = @temp_arr;

   my $message = join ("\n",@temp_arr);
   print "Content-Type: text/xml\r\n";
   print "\r\n";
   print "$message\n";
```

I get this error message when opened using FF browser:

Error loading stylesheet: A network error occurred loading an XSLT stylesheet:http://&ltmachine_name&gt/cgi-bin/myquery.xsl

Answer (score 0):

Finally it worked.

Added "/" before the XSL file

push(@temp_arr,"\<\?xml-stylesheet type\=\"text/xsl\" href\=\"/myquery.xsl\"\?>");

And copied the XSK file to 'DocumentRoot' as per Apache settings

In my case, 'DocumentRoot' is set to '/var/www/html'